# Is it possible to map POJO fields with names different from the table columns?

Tags: java, xml, ibatis

I am relatively new to ibatis. I know it is already upgraded to mybatis, but for some reason I have to use ibatis. My question is that "Is it possible to map POJO fields with names different from the table columns?"

I have a table, the mapping file, and the POJO class. I can successfully read data if my POJO class has names exactly the same as the columns in the table, but if I name the field something else, it does not work. I changed the corresponding getter and defined a resultMap in the mapping file like the following

```
<resultMap id="result" class="Subscriber">
    <result column="AdvisorId" property="id" jdbcType="INTEGER"/>
    <result column="FirstName" property="FirstName" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/> 
    <result column="LastName" property="LastName" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/> 
    <result column="EmailId" property="EmailId222" jdbcType="VARCHAR"/>
</resultMap>

<select id="getAll" resultMap="result">
    SELECT AdvisorId,FirstName,LastName,EmailId FROM communication
</select>
```

Here as an example, I am trying to rename EmailId in my POJO field to EmailId222

Comment: Yes this should work as long as there is a property named EmailId222 in Subscriber bean with proper getEmailId222  and setEmailId222 methods.

Comment: @Ankit, I did not have the setter. Now I added it, but still does not work.

Comment: Yes, without the setter ibatis will not know to which field EmailId needs to be mapped with.

Answer (score 0):

In the *Subscriber* class you have to define *getter* and *setter* methods for the field. Be careful to use capital letters if necessary. Then you have to restart your application to make the changes work. In your case, you should implement:

```
getEmailId222(){...}

setEmailId222(String EmailId222){...}
```